# when is a @Column annotation required for persistent properties of JPA classes?

Tags: java, jpa

In my JPA model I typically annotate each persistent class with @Entity and each persistent property with an appropriate annotation e.g. @Id, @Column, @ManyToOne, etc. A typical example is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class StoredFile {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

I was looking at [this example entity class](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-jpa-crud/src/main/java/com/baeldung/softdelete/Product.java) and noticed that only the `id` field has a JPA annotation, i.e. there are no annotations specified for `name` or `price`.

Under what circumstances will a property of an `@Entity` be persisted if there are no annotations on the field/getter/setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify `@Column` annotation to persist a bean property.

`@Column` has to be used to specify a name of a table column. So if a [naming strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy) is used, you don't need to use `@Column`.

My advice is to always use `@Column` even if you don't need to specify a name.

```
@Column
private String fileName;
```

Also never mix fields and getters annotations.

Everything is primary for Hibernate.